# Authoring PDFs in HTML, CSS, and JavaScript

Tags: css, dom, pdf

I really really like creating objects via the DOM + CSS.

Is there anyway that I can

- take a snapshot of the DOM tree, and
- produce a PDF out of the DOM tree

(It's perfectly fine is the interactivity is lost. I just like the intuitive manner in which DOM trees can be created.)

Comment: Check this out http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[PrinceXML](http://www.princexml.com/)** is a professional tool for creating PDF from HTML with CSS styling. Its price is also *professional* ;) (from USD500 for offline use on one computer to USD3800 for a server licence) so it won't be OK for a hobby.
Edit: oops, it has also "*a free license for non-commercial use of Prince. This license adds a small logo to the first page of generated PDF files.*"

It has always had very good support of CSS2.1 (`print` media included, obviously)

Comment: +1! -- For best results if CSS is involved: use PrinceXML, yes (says someone who has tested and used a *lot* of different PDF creation utilities...).

Answer (score 2):

On Kubuntu Linux one can print to PDF from any application, such as Firefox. You may want to look into a printer-to-PDF driver for your OS. Note that you will have to be very careful about pagebreaks, however. CSS can handle that so long as you know which size paper you are targeting.

Comment: This is a good idea; there are many free Print-to-PDF drivers for Windows.